# How to change Druid Historical service Tier

Tags: druid

I have a configured Druid cluster with 6 historical services. All services belong to the default tier. I'm interested in the simplest way to make a change so that 2 of the Historicals are in the new (hot) tier, while the remaining 4 stay in the default tier. The 4 Historicals have enough resources to handle everything that was previously running on the 6 Historicals. Can I simply restart one Historical at a time with the new config and wait for the data from that Historical to replicate to another server?

Considering that I need to make this change on a production cluster, and I don't have a staging environment, it was a risk to try anything :)

Answer (score 0):

There is always risk in production.
That said, you can change the tier of two historicals and have the coordinator do the rebalancing.
Assuming the two nodes you are moving to "hot" have some of the segments they will end up with anyway, you might want to define the retention rules that will use the hot tier ahead of time too. This will make decisions to move segments take the final desired data distribution into account.

A potentially "safer" way, is to do this step by step. First mark the two historicals as `decommissioningNodes` in the [Coordinators Dynamic Configuration](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration/#dynamic-configuration). This will move all the segments off of those nodes and into the remaining four. You can then safely re-config the two nodes to `hot`, restart them and take them off the `decommissioningNodes` list.